# How to access a connection handle from one class in another class in php

Tags: php, pdo

I´m building a MVC application. My PDO connection is in /Controller/includes/Conexao and queries are in /model/DAO

As I need a prepared statement I need to use the connection handle like that:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
```

Problem is that $db is a variable in my class Conexão and I am not able to use it in DAO class. So how could I proceed?

Using old fashioned php code I could only call mysql_query but it is about to be discontinued so that´s not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using globals unless there is a VERY good reason for doing so. Look into dependency injection and singletons. There is a very nice light-weight container called Pimple that can be used for this purpose:

http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

Another uglier solution would be using mysqli_query (only the old mysql is deprecated).